# I installed php7.4 version in ubuntu and after that I am enabling mbstring in ubuntu but it keeps showing me error

Tags: 22.04, apache2, php, lamp, composer

In picture it is clear that installed version of php is 7.4 and when I enable mbstring extension with

`sudo phpenmod mbstring`

it keeps showing me the error. I have attached screenshot for it.

[image: Screenshot showing error message]

Comment: Please include the error and version info in the question not as a picture.

Comment: Please check the description of the question. I wrote the version as well. You can click on the text "Screenshot of error and php version" for further details also about error also.

Comment: Don't you see that I also mentioned in description?

Answer (score 0):

Install the mbstring package first then try enabling.

`sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring`